# validate multiple radio button groups using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, radio-button

I have 6 sets of radio buttons, all independent of each other. Im using JQuery validation plugin to validate them(they are all required). However the validation only works on the first one the 'satisfaction' group. My validation code is here

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#surveyForm").validate({
    rules: {
        satisfaction: {
            required: true
        },

        responding: {
            required: true
        },

        listening: {
            required: true
        },

        solution: {
            required: true
        },

        communication: {
            required: true
        },

        professional: {
            required: true
        }

    },
    messages:{
        satisfaction: {
            required: "this"
        },

        responding: {
            required: "is"
        },

        listening: {
            required: "a"
        },

        solution: {
            required: "test"
        },

        communication: {
            required: "to"
        },

        professional: {
            required: "see"
        }
    }
});
```

});

Any suggestions?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p7yP/)

Comment: Can you show your HTML and make a fiddle?

Comment: I added a js fiddle to illustrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had `<div id="q1">` before `<form id="surveyForm">`, so the matching `</div>` was terminating the form.

Change the order of those two lines and the problem is resolved.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8p7yP/4/)

Comment: That was it! thanks, I cant believe I made such a stupid mistake

Comment: The browser's DOM inspector is a wonderful thing, learn to use it.